# Is this proof logically sound?

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, pigeonhole-principle

Consider 17 students and three subjects: Maths, Science, and History. Any two students gossip with each other about exactly one of those three modules. Prove that there exist three students gossiping with each other about the same module.

If possible could someone validate this proof:

Since each student gossips with one other student, there are ceiling(17/2) = 8 separate conversations.

Since there are 3 subjects ceiling(8/3) = 3

So by the pigeonhole principle, there must exist three students gossiping about the same subjects. Is this ok?

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: No.  this is not okay.  There are many more than eight conversations of three students going on, there are in fact $\binom{17}{3}$ different conversations.  The problem reworded is to consider a complete graph with $17$ vertices and edges each colored one of three colors.  Your task is to prove that there exists at least one monochromatic triangle in the graph.

Comment: Have you heard of Ramsey Theory?  Have you seen the proof yet that a complete graph on six vertices with edges colored one of two colors necessarily has a monochromatic triangle?  (*party of six people, at least three mutual friends or three mutual non-aquaintences*)?  Can you modify that proof to fit this?

Comment: what @JMoravitz said, but there are $\binom{17}{2} = 136$ conversations.

Comment: @Joffan I was referring to three-person conversations

Comment: @JMoravitz OK - well, we'll take this as a clarification anyway. The number eight in question text seemed to me to be referring to two-person conversations (even though technically the calculation stated should have given nine, they're all wrong anyway)

Comment: @treebluefire: It seems to me that you are solving a slightly different problem. Namely, if 17 students in pairs are gossiping about three subjects at the same time, then there will be three pairs of students gossiping about the same subject. 

However, the condition of the problem does not assume that all gossiping happens at the same time. The process can be spread over many days or even years. Each student must gossip with each other.

Comment: After looking at all the above comments and specifically at @kabenyuk I am solving a different problem entirely, I will look up Ramsey's theory as suggested by JM. Does anyone know of any way of solving this by pigeonhole principle?

Comment: @Joffan what does a 3 person conversation even represent? Would that not just be a cycle of three nodes?

Comment: @treebluefire at that point we are into [hypergraphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) (with hyperedges joining more than two nodes) and my brain melts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved in two steps.

1. First, let us prove that if we have only two subjects (maths and science) and six students and any two students gossip with each other about exactly one of those two subjects. Prove that there exist three students gossiping with each other about the same two subject.

*Solution.* Take an arbitrary student, say John. He gossips with five others about our two subjects. By the pigeonhole principle, there are at least three students with whom John gossips about the same subject, say maths.

If those three students gossip with each other about science, then the problem is solved.

If at least two of those three are gossiping about maths, add John to that couple and we've solved the problem again.

2. Your case with three subjects and 17 students reduces to case 1 in the same way. Try it on your own.